# Adiabatic process and internal energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, reversibility, adiabatic

My question concerns the connection between change in internal energy $dE = Q - W$ and the available work in an adiabatic process.

My understanding is, that in an adiabatic process ($Q=0$) the change in internal energy is simply the availiable work $dE = - W$. However, in the textbook *Equilibrium statistical physics* by Plischke it says on page 10,

> The decrease in internal energy is equal to the maximum amount of work obtainable through an adiabatic process, and this maximum is achieved if the process is reversible.

Can anyone spot a flaw in my thinking or is it simply a typo in the textbook?

Comment: Which part should be a typo? What is the issue?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/577374/on-the-meaning-of-du-delta-w-for-adiabatic-processes?rq=1 in particular, Chet Miller's answer.

Comment: Thank you GiorgioP the link is very helpful! 
Steeven: My issue is that the textbook suggests different adiabatic paths provide different amounts of work. He states that $\Delta E$ is the maximum amount of work obtainable in an adiabatic process, but surely $\Delta E$ is the only amount of heat we might obtain if the process is adiabatic (both reversibly and irreversibly).

Comment: If the process is adiabatic, there is no heat obtained.

Comment: I ment to write work in the last sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

In case of an isothermal process $\Delta U=0$.
In case of an adiabatic process, $\Delta Q=0$.
Both of your statements are correct.
No typo I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your response Yash Tandon. I believe you mean to say that $T=$constant for an isothermal process? Either way, I am only worried about adiabatic processes in this question :)

Comment: Yes ,u r right ,,,,i meant T=0...Anytime:)

Answer (score 0):

The change in internal energy is the maximum *possible* work that can be done, but the actual work done is not necessarily the maximum possible work.

The actual work that is done is the maximum possible when the adiabatic process is reversible, i.e., carried out very slowly (quasi-statically) without any mechanical friction.

If, for example, mechanical friction is involved, then some of the internal energy is wasted to overcome that friction leaving less internal energy available to perform productive work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bob D. Thank you for your response. I does help - however, the situation i'm considering is rather idealized where all available work is extractable. I have discovered the solution for my original question in the link posted by GiorgioP.